# get 403 forbidden only happens with url1 not url2

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-403

I do a 'get' (javascript)

```
$.get("ME.php?uid="+uid+"&screen="+screen+"&icon="+icot+"&jhtml="+temp+"&F=seticon",function(data){/*doStuff*/});
```

And this url works fine with zero error:

```
http://mysite.com/ME.php?uid=1&screen=custom&icon=hubpages&jhtml=<div id='hubpages' style='position: absolute; left: 818px; top: 31px; z-index: -9; ' class='icon ui-draggable' ><img src='M/hubpages.png'><div class='box'><a href='http://hubpages.com' target='_blank'>hubpages.com</a></div></div>&F=seticon
```

But I get 403 forbidden with this request:

```
http://mysite.com/ME.php?uid=1&screen=custom&icon=squidoo&jhtml=<div id='squidoo' style='position: absolute; left: 307px; top: -35px; z-index: -9; ' class='icon ui-draggable' ><img src='M/squidoo.png'><div class='box'><a href='http://squidoo.com' target='_blank'>squidoo.com</a></div></div>&F=seticon
```

I just can't spot the difference, there is only so many hours I can look at this with out going crazy! They are the same!? 6:30am, Maybe I have already lost my mind...

If it helps; I am doing both these gets in the same function, on the same line/with the same line, the function performs the same action on each url.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a 403 error, it's likely your problem lies on the server side. I'd imagine the issue likely has something to do with the very long jhtml parameter, which you seem to be passing without any encoding. Ideally, you wouldn't pass an HTML string like this, but if it's absolutely essential, you could try using `encodeURI()` on the HTML string before you make the request, then use your server-side technology's complementary method to decode it.

Comment: I will try your encodeURI() suggestion. I think you sort of missed the point though mate, as length has nothing to do with it as the first working url is longer than the second 403 url. Thanks

Comment: GET 403 (Forbidden) jquery.js:4